# How to deliver google scholar alerts at specific time

Tags: google-scholar

I get google scholar alerts at all times of the day. This irritates me because it comes up as an email, I dont have time to read it, and then I forget about it.

My only reading time is Friday morning so it would be great to get my alerts at 8.00am on Friday morning as that would be consistent with my workflow.

The question is therefore can I get my alerts delivered on Friday 08.00 and not before then- a kind of weekly digest?

Comment: So, if you don't read them then they are still unread. When you got time you can just read the not yet read mails so you don't miss them?

Comment: What is the point? You can just not read them until Friday morning.

Answer (score 8):

[Create a filter](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6579?hl=en) to add a label to the emails.

Then every Friday you can read all the emails marked with that label!

Comment: This is definitely a good start. Honestly, I wish I had a way to prevent myself from clicking on these labels the moment something shows up, though!

Comment: Good answer.  @AJK - I use Thunderbird and gmail together.  My "favorite" folders are displayed normally, but what I can do is, on Friday, toggle over to "All Folders."  This would solve your problem.  Alternatively you could subscribe to Google Alerts with a different email account, which you would only read once a week.

Answer (score 3):

There is no option to change the frequency of the Google Scholar alerts that you have subscribed to. It is better to ask the Google Scholar support team directly. You can only change the number of results that you want to see a list in your email.

I understand that it is sometimes annoying looking at 3-4 emails daily on various topics. If you are really not reading the list and not following the work, it is better to unsubscribe (or 'Cancel') the alert by logging into your account.